# Woocommerce Product Variation Tax Query Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, parameters, arguments

I'm sure I've either missed something really simple, but is there a reason why this doesn't work?

```
global $post;
$product_id = $post->ID;
$args = array(
'post_type'     => array('product_variation'),
'posts_per_page'   => -1,
'post_parent'   => 177,
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'pa_billing-period',
        'terms' => 'yearly',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'include_children' => true,
        'operator' => 'IN'
    )
),
);

$variations = get_posts( $args ); 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($variations); echo "</pre>";
```

I'm trying to output a specific variation but I'm getting absolutely nothing. If I remove the tax_query, all 4 variations show.

Any ideas what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     => array('product_variation'),
'posts_per_page'   => -1,
'post_parent'   => 177,
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'attribute_pa_billing-period',
        'value' => 'yearly'
    )
),
);
```